# Import in VSCode without using .mjs files

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, import

I'm having trouble importing files in JavaScript. I am fairly new to the language and have followed a couple of VSCode tutorials that demonstrate and explain importing. Their importing seems to work out of the box, with one tutorial setting up his files like this, which worked for him:
[image: Working import]

I also made sure to set up my index.html properly to use ES6 module imports. My index.html looks like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>JS Modules</title>
    <script type="module" src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

But no matter what I do, the only way I can get VSCode to handle imports and not give this error

> SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

is by changing my .js files to .mjs files (which makes my imports function properly). I have a vague understanding that this is because of how JS is implemented using Node in VSCode and Node does not play nicely with imports(?), but am not completely clear on that.

I have also browsed other questions about this topic, **but none explain why those tutorial videos are able to use imports seemingly out-of-the-box in VSCode with .js file extensions when I cannot**, so if someone could shed light on this that would be much appreciated.

EDIT:
My JavaScript code (copied from [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cRHQNNcYf6s&t=261s)):

main.js:

```
import User from './user.js'

const user = new User('Bob', 11);
console.log(user)
```

user.js:

```
export default class User {
    constructor(name, age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
}

export function printName(user) {
    console.log(`User's name is ${user.name}`)
}

export function printAge(user) {
    console.log(`User's age is ${user.age}`)
}
```

Comment: You have to use a relative, not bare, path with the module. So `<script type="module" src="./main.js"></script>` (note the `./` before `main.js`). Similarly, in `main.js`, don't use `/user.js`, use something relative (if it's a peer file, `./user.js`).

Comment: Please post code (including the initial code showing the error), error messages, markup, and other textual information **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Sorry - the picture I posted is from the youtube video to show what the code that worked looked like. My code is identical to the pictured code, but I can edit my post to include my code, as well. Also, editing the paths to be relative does not fix the error.